# Improving the my sql query for doing search for text in all columns of the table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, search

I have to implement the feature where in user inputs some text in the search field and I need to query and pull out the items related to that text from the table.In the table I have close to 8 columns which are user facing and 4 columns which are auto inserted whenever insert happens via front end.

Below is query I wrote and it works in via mysql client,

```
select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * 
from `database`.`ttable` 
WHERE testdatetime BETWEEN '2012/05/01' and '2012/09/27' 
and testimg IS NOT NULL 
and testtitle LIKE 't%' 
OR testname LIKE 't%' 
OR testaddr LIKE 't%'  
OR testph LIKE 't%' 
OR testoffs LIKE't%' 
OR testmaps LIKE 't%' 
OR testimg LIKE 't%' 
OR testdatetime LIKE 't%'  
order  by testdatetime desc;
```

Now for some reason this query looks bit odd to me as I am checking each column for that value, and wanted to check if this is right way to implement it or mysql has some built it features which yields better results than this query.Appreciate if someone can point me to right direction.Since I am yet to implement this feature,I dont know how it performs in terms of performance,but I know Like clauses are bit intensive in operations.

Comment: I might be alone on this but using BETWEEN always worries me.  Depending on the database it could be a > or < situation or a >= or <= situation or a mix of those two.... (I think?).

Comment: I would like to avoid > or < but can think of >= or <= .. let me check this.

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off using full text search for your string searches rather than like statements. That way you can also find variants of the search terms. Here's a link on full-text searches for MySQL http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: as per docs full text search works only for myisam and I am with innodb.I would love to use it as this approach looks clean compare to using between and like.version I am using is My sql version 5.5.13 with Innodb engine.Seems like only upgrade will give me this benefit.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a built in feature to do what you want. It's called a full text index. It will be way more efficient than a bunch of like statements. Here's something to get you started.

http://www.databasejournal.com/sqletc/article.php/1578331/Using-Fulltext-Indexes-in-MySQL---Part-1.htm